# How to clear memory when I close program in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form (Shown in image)

[image: Main Form]

I want my program to clear its memory when I click the close button to close my program in devexpress. How can I do that?

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: If you're only using managed memory the memory will be released automatically when you close your program. This is default behaviour of .NET.

Comment: In .Net you do not have to worry about memory if you do not using unmanaged resources. After closing the memory in applications cleans itself (generally speaking)

Comment: If you want to actually __clear__ the memory used, I doubt you can do that, unless you have allocated it as __fixed__. If you care about the memory being __freed__, this happens automatically with manged memory.